# Symfony Entity Validate

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I'm using symfony 2.7 version.
i try to do validate, and it's works fine,
just the message for the validate not working.
for exmple, email validate:

```
 /**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *      message = "Email empty";
 * )
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $email;
```

i'm still get the default message:
"This value should not be blank."
i recreate the Entity file, and Run

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User
```

and still the default message.
i turn
 `validation:      { enable_annotations: true }`
no any changes.
i see the errors, by :

```
var_dump($errors);
```

so custuom message not work at all.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

the message option must be written between the parentheses:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Email empty";
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $email;
```